# Unity 2D Animator, confusion on parameters and transitions for platform 2d character

Tags: animation, unityscript

I am new to designing games and have been having trouble for the past couple of days with the animator.  I have downloaded a free asset off the Unity store that included a free sprite character and also its animations for idle, walk, run, and jump.  My issue is when I go to use this asset pack in my game, I can not for the life of me figure out how to transition between idle->walk, and any state->jump.  I believe it has to do with no parameters being set up, as I want the walk animation to occur when my character is moving.  The issue is that it seems to be stuck in idle mode.  In the animator the transitions are set up, but I can not figure out how to let the animator know when I am moving, and when I am actually idle.  How can I connect my characters movement scripts to be used in conjunction with the animation?  Do I need to write a new script, that uses new parameters I make in the animator, or am I completely missing something?  Again I am very new at this, so I apologize if this is a dumb question but I cannot figure it out.  All the videos I have watched only show how to build the animations and put them into the animator, and nothing about the scripts or parameters in specific.  Thank you!

Comment: [This](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/animation/animator-scripting?playlist=17099) may be helpful.

Comment: Thanks! The video was definitely helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the animation transition requirements, then set the required values. For example:

```
Animator anim = obj.GetComponent<Animator>();
anim.SetTrigger("running");
```

or

```
anim.SetFloat("speed", 2);
```

or

```
anim.SetBool("running", true);
```

One small thing that could be going wrong: If you somehow have a reference to the prefab instead of the instantiated object in your scene, it will not work. And to be sure it's not working, play the game, find the object with the Animator in the Hierarchy, click it, and open the Animator window. You can see which state is active.

If this doesn't help, can you describe the transitions in more detail?

Comment: That makes sense,  thank you!  I am pretty sure your answer is exactly what I needed to know.  I am at work for awhile but I will be testing this later on today.  Ill edit my posting if I can not figure it out, but I believe I should be able to now.   Thanks again!